# Load UIImagePickerController in background

Tags: iphone, multithreading, synchronization

When my app starts I would like to initialize an `UIImagePickerController`. Since this can take several seconds, I would like to do it in the background. What is the best way to ensure that the background task finished, before invoking the picker?

Currently I have the following code. It works, but it will crash if one invokes the picker before the background task is done.

```
 - (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear: animated];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initPicker) withObject:nil];


    ....

 }
```

and

```
 - (void)  initPicker {
      NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

      NSLog(@"picker start... ");
      [self setPicker: [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]];

      NSLog(@"picker done.");

      [pool release];

  }
```

Thank you!

**Edit:** It turns our this question is somewhat theoretical. Computing `[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]` only takes time in *debug mode on the device*. So for production code, there is no need to run anything in the background. Also,  `[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]` seems to lock the main thread, so even in debug mode there is no advantage of placing it on a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [NSConditionLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html) for signaling that your controller is loaded.  In the -initPicker method I would set the condition when the UIImagePickerController is finish initializing.  And in your IBAction for the showing the picker, I would check for that condition. For more options, see [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Multithreading.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simple flag can do the job ?

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
     BOOL _pickerIsLoaded;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _pickerIsLoaded = NO;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initPicker) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)initPicker
{
      NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

      NSLog(@"picker start... ");
      [self setPicker: [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]];
      NSLog(@"picker done.");

      _pickerIsLoaded = YES;

      [pool release];

} 

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you wait until your "picker done" and then add the picker view to whatever view makes it visible?
Something like this, right after your "picker done" statment:

```
   [self presentModalViewController: theImagePickerController]; // assuming self is a viewController.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't think this will work. First, UI-calls can only be done on the main thread. Second, the goal is not to present the ImagePicker as soon as it is loaded. Only after the user taps a button.